# Re-create a wav file read into a buffer of double values (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, buffer, wav

I have used the following code (Based on the code found at this site: http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) to read a wav file and create a buffer of double values (audio Frames):

```
    // Open the wav file specified as the first argument
        WavFile wavFile = WavFile.openWavFile(new File("recording_1536059009.wav"));

        sampleRate = (int) wavFile.getSampleRate();

        System.out.println("SR " + sampleRate);

        // Display information about the wav file
        wavFile.display();


        System.out.println("");

        // Create a variable that stores number of frames in file.
        int numFrames = (int) wavFile.getNumFrames();

        double duration = numFrames/sampleRate;

        System.out.println("duration is  " + duration);


        // Get the number of audio channels in the wav file
        int numChannels = wavFile.getNumChannels();

        // Create a buffer of frames
        double[] buffer = new double[numFrames * numChannels];

        int framesRead;

        do {
            // Read frames into buffer
            framesRead = wavFile.readFrames(buffer, numFrames);

        } while (framesRead != 0);
```

I then split the buffer into chunks of high energy sections based on a threshold value : (Chunks are groups of consecutive frames (double values) that are higher than this threshold they will look somthing like this).

```
                      3.0517578125E-5
                      9.1552734375E-5
                      3.0517578125E-5
                      9.1552734375E-5
```

This is the code I used to divide the buffer of double values into these "chunks" making up  significant event.

```
    ArrayList<Double> significantEvent = new ArrayList<Double>();

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> significantEventCollect = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

    for (int loop = 0; loop <  buffer.length; loop++) {


        if (buffer[loop] >= threshold) {
            significantEvent.add(buffer[loop]);
             System.out.println(buffer[loop]);

        } else if (buffer[loop] < threshold && significantEvent.size() > 0) {
             System.out.println("");



            significantEventCollect.add(significantEvent);



            significantEvent = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

I would like to turn these chunks back into their own wav file so they can be played back.

So far I have not found away to achieve this with this data alone.

Any guidance about my next steps for this would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Where are the chunks, I cannot understand what data represents what you call chunk.

Comment: @jazz64 Apologies I have edited the question to clarify this better.